# w8 default tablet settings conflicts with WPF layout

Tags: wpf, windows-8, alignment, tablet, windows-8.1

I have a WPF desktop app. I've gotten reports from W8 users that the code completion window in our app is not aligned correctly. I investigated and found out that its a setting in W8 tablet settings that conflicts with the placement of popups in wpf

[image: Tablet settings]

Default is right handed and then the code completion popup looks like this
[image]

When changed to left handed the code completion popup renders correctly like this
[image]

Is there a way to programmaticly force the app to use left handed settings, or ignore it completely so it renders like in w7?

edit: Got an upwote so can update with solution, requires .NET 4.5

```
private static readonly FieldInfo MenuDropAlignmentField;

static MyWindow()
{
    MenuDropAlignmentField = typeof (SystemParameters).GetField("_menuDropAlignment",
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(MenuDropAlignmentField != null);

    EnsureStandardPopupAlignment();
    SystemParameters.StaticPropertyChanged += (s, e) => EnsureStandardPopupAlignment();
}

private static void EnsureStandardPopupAlignment()
{
    if (SystemParameters.MenuDropAlignment && MenuDropAlignmentField != null)
    {
        MenuDropAlignmentField.SetValue(null, false);
    }
}
```

Full code here

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE/blob/master/FreePIE.GUI/Shells/MainShellView.xaml.cs